# Have pacmatic wrap yay wrap powerpill wrap pacman

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, manjaro, pacman

I have a few preferences in regards to managing packages on Manjaro / Arch:

- [`pacmatic`](http://kmkeen.com/pacmatic/) adds safety features when installing packages
- [`yay`](https://github.com/Jguer/yay) provides a consistent interface to both the official and AUR packages
- [`powerpill`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Powerpill) for parallel, accelerated downloading of packages
- `pacman` with `/etc/pacman.conf` options `Color` and `UseDelta` (for the win)

How can I have `pacmatic` call `yay` using `powerpill` instead of `pacman`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your (non-root) user's `~/.bashrc`, add:

```bsh
alias pac=yay  # For convenience

# pacmatic needs to be run as root: https://github.com/keenerd/pacmatic/issues/35
alias pacmatic='sudo --preserve-env=pacman_program /usr/bin/pacmatic'

# Downgrade permissions as AUR helpers expect to be run as a non-root user. $UID is read-only in {ba,z}sh.
alias yay='pacman_program="sudo -u #$UID /usr/bin/yay --pacman powerpill" pacmatic'
```

Now when typing `pac`, this will invoke `pacmatic` for safety, which will in turn execute `yay` which will use `powerpill` for fast downloading.

---

You probably also want to [set `aria2`'s `--console-log-level=warn`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-console-log-level) for a bit of hush in the [`powerpill.json` configuration](https://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/powerpill/#powerpill.json1).

Comment: You may want to handle a default arg such as `-Syu` if you're used to running `yay` without any arguments to update like I am.